# Oracle - How to check values from multiple records and if one values matches - use it for larger dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Here's my data:

```
Step   random_task     Status         date
1        do_this      Completed       1-Nov-2020
1        do-that      Cancelled       2-Nov-2020
2        do_this     Not Assigned     1-Nov-2020
2        do_that      Cancelled       2-Nov-2020
2        and_that     Cancelled       2-Nov-2020
3        do_this      Cancelled       2-Nov-2020
3        do_that      Cancelled       2-Nov-2020
3        also_that    Cancelled       2-Nov-2020
4        do_that      In Progress or Scheduled or whatever   1-Nov-2020
4        and_that     Completed       2-Nov-2020
```

**Grouping by Steps:**

Completed = If all tasks in the Step have APS_Status__c = “Completed”.

Completed = If at least 1 Task is "Completed" and ALL remaining tasks = "Cancelled".

Not Started = If at least 1 Task is “Not Assigned” and ALL remaining tasks = "Cancelled".

Not Started = If all tasks in the Step have APS_Status__c = “Not Assigned”.

Cancelled = If all tasks in the Step have APS_Status__c = “Cancelled”.

In Progress = If at least 1 Task is <> "Completed" or "Cancelled" or "Not Assigned".

**Output:**

```
Step       Status            date 
1          Completed         2-Nov-2020 (if status = completed, then max(date) of that step
2          Not Started      (null)
3          Cancelled        (null)
4          In Progress      (null)
```

I have tried adding assigning values to like 100, -100 & 0, summing it up and then extracting mod(sum,100) to determing the correct value. But I am unable to assign the max(date) for that step.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to write a query yourself yet?

Comment: Hi Tim

Yes, let me edit and add that to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as:

```
select step,
       (case when min(status) = max(status) and min(status) in ('Completed', 'Cancelled')
             then min(status)
             when sum(case when status in ('Completed', 'Cancelled') then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
             then 'Completed'
             when sum(case when status in ('Not Assigned', 'Cancelled') then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
             then 'Not Started'
             then ''
             else 'In Progress'
       end) as status,
       (case when min(status) = max(status) and min(status) in 'Completed'
             then max(date)
        end)
from t
group by step;
```

These slightly simplify your logic.  In particular, the "Completed" and "Cancelled" are handled first in the logic -- if all statuses are the same.  Then a step is "Not Started" if all statuses are "Not Assigned" or "Cancelled".

Comment: Thank you Gordon, this worked and looks very simple to understand. I was trying mod() and then extracting numbers etc. This is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GROUP BY and conditional aggregate as follows:

```
SELECT STEP, STATUS, CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Completed' THEN DATE END AS DATE FROM
(SELECT STEP,
       DATE,
       CASE WHEN COMPLETED = TOTAL THEN 'Completed' 
            WHEN (COMPLETED >= 1 AND CANCELLED = TOTAL - COMPLETED) 
                 OR (NOTASSIGNED >= 1 AND CANCELLED = TOTAL - NOTASSIGNED) THEN 'Cancelled'
            WHEN NOTASSIGNED = TOTAL THEN 'Not Assigned'
            WHEN CANCELLED = TOTAL THEN 'Cancelled'
        END AS STATUS
FROM
(SELECT STEP,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Completed' THEN 1 END) AS COMPLETED,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Cancelled' THEN 1 END) AS CANCELLED,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Not Assigned' THEN 1 END) AS NOTASSIGNED,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'In Progress' THEN 1 END) AS INPROGRESS,
       COUNT(1) AS TOTAL,
       MAX(DATE) AS DATE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY STEP))
```

I am not sure about In progress condition so please take care of it by yourself.